# How to take a screenshot of a window

Tags: java, ubuntu, native

How do you take a screenshot of an external application window using Java on Ubuntu. I don't want to use the Robot class or any sort of similar method. I want to do a "native" sort of method. I'm looking for something similar to the JNI approach of this on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in 2 ways:

1. Alt + Print Screen to take a screenshot of a window.
2. Shift + Print Screen to take a screenshot of an area you select.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: I see what you did there , but this is indeed like Abra said.